# Convert LINQ select to a understandable for-loop

Tags: c#, linq

I try to understand this LINQ and convert it to a for-loop but I can't figured out.

```
var valueAsString = "00000a3d003d";
var parts = valueAsString.ToCharArray();
var formatted = parts.Select((p, i) => (++i) % 2 == 0 ? String.Concat(p.ToString(), " ") : p.ToString());
string ret = String.Join(String.Empty, formatted).Trim();
```

Comment: The variable is is the index that starts at zero and increases by one for each item in parts.  Looks like code is putting a space after odd items.  So all code is doing is changing "00000a3d003d"; to "00 00 0a 3d 00 3d";

Comment: Note that `string ret = String.Join(String.Empty, formatted).Trim();` is just a weird way of doing `string.Concat(formatted).Trim();`

Comment: `int i = 0; var sb = new StringBuilder(); foreach(char p in valueAsString){ sb.Append(p); if((++i) % 2 == 0) sb.Append(" "); } string ret = sb.ToString().Trim();`

Comment: IMO using a loop won't make the code more understandable at all unless you don't know what `Select()` does (which you should). A _very_ opinionated intro to LINQ by myself: https://github.com/bert2/love-linq-hate-loops

Comment: The `++i` is useless and obfuscates the intent of the code more than the actual use of LINQ.

Comment: @ZevSpitz that's probably what led to OP's question. I think OP falsely assumed that the `++i` changes `i` for _all_ iterations of `Select()` where in reality that particular `i` is thrown away as soon as the lambda is finished. The original author really should have written `(i + 1) % 2`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride And of course, there's the odd use of `String.Concat` instead of `+` or `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```cs
private void LinqLoop2()
{
    var valueAsString = "00000a3d003d";
    var ret = "";

    for (var i = 1; i <= valueAsString.Length; i++)
    {
        var p = valueAsString[i - 1];

        ret += p;

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            ret += " ";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(ret.Trim());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The `Select()` function in the `Linq` statement is the loop. You're looping through each character in the string and appending a space after each group of two characters.

End result: `00 00 0a 3d 00 3d`